# How to get plain value (remove node) in Step function AWS cli

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm working with AWS cli to create an Step function, but i don't know how to remove one node from the result object

I want to add a value to an existing object, for example i have

```json
{
    "info": {
        "firstname": "Nicolas",
        "valueMaybeNull": "Hola"
    },
    "request": {
        "data": {
            "currency": "EUR",
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to verify if the value is null and added to the `request.data.newName`

So i have made this code

```java
var isValueEmptyStep = new Choice(scope, "Is value not empty?");


Chain verifyIfValueIsNullStep =
    isValueEmptyStep
    .when(
        Condition.and(
            Condition.isPresent("$.info.valueMaybeNull"),
            Condition.isNotNull("$.info.valueMaybeNull")),
        addValueState(scope))
    .otherwise(new Pass(scope, "Value is null, continue normally"))
    .afterwards();

return Chain.start(verifyIfValueIsNullStep);
}

public Pass addValueState(final Construct scope) {

    return Pass.Builder.create(scope, "Add value to request data")
        .parameters(Map.of("newName.$", "$.info.valueMaybeNull"))
        .resultPath("$.request.data.newName")
        .build();
}
```

The result is

```json
{
    "info": {
        "firstname": "Nicolas",
        "valueMaybeNull": "Hola"
    },
    "request": {
        "data": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "newValue": {
                "newName": "Hola"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to have

```json
{
    "info": {
        "firstname": "Nicolas",
        "valueMaybeNull": "Hola"
    },
    "request": {
        "data": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "newValue": "Hola"
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how to remove the node `newValue.newValue` created, I didn't found a way to remove the level or use the plain text.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i only needed to use the inputPath to evaluate the value ex

```
public Pass addValueState(final Construct scope) {

    return Pass.Builder.create(scope, "Add value to request data")
        .inputPath("$.info.valueMaybeNull")
        .resultPath("$.request.data.newName")
        .build();
}
```